# Проблема отображения меню копировать/вставить Android EditText

Tags: java, android, edittext

На одном из экранов приложения заметил, что в EditText при выделении слова не вызывается контекстное меню копирования/вставки текста. Причем longclick на пустом поле ввода работает так, как нужно.

Ситуация эта замечена только в одном контексте, в этой Activity.
Попытки следовать советам и добавить элементу `android:textIsSelectable="true"` ни к чему не привели.
Может кто-то еще сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Привожу код своего EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnSend"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnSend"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btnStickers"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnStickers"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background_white_border_corners"
        android:hint="@string/type_message"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: Покажите свой код вызова контекстного меню

Comment: @Barmaley я не использую кастомное меню, только встроенное в компонент.